# How to restart android app and return to the same fragment?

Tags: android, android-intent, application-restart

I know how to restart an app and return to same Activity

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
requireActivity().finishAffinity(); 
requireActivity().startActivity(settingsIntent);    
System.exit(0);
```

But how to return to same fragment as well?

ps: i am using jetpack navigation components

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the activity, you can keep value for which fragment of the activity to return back to.
If you want to do this even when app is **killed by system** which mostly the case for better UX, in new jetpack library you can use **savedState**(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#6). PS: This is still not a stable version of savedState.

Comment: Since i could not use the savedState, I ended up using sharepreferences to keep a boolean which if true will start the settings fragment using 'findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.settings_dest)'.  I don't like this solution but it is the best i encountered. I upvoted but i did not mark as the answer since i was not sure savedState was the way to go in this case.